# Integral of $\sqrt{4-\sin^2(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So we have to find the antiderivative of $\sqrt{4-\sin^2x}$. 
What I did was to put $\sin x=t;\cos xdx=dt$. 
But now I am not able to calculate the integral of $\sqrt\frac{4-x^2}{1-x^2}$. 
So how to initiate the solution of the problem? Please guide. 
WolframAlpha says something elliptic, which I dont know yet. So plase help.

Comment: The derivative of your integral is indeed an elliptic integral of the second kind. Where did you get your problem from?

Comment: My math teacher at school.

Comment: Look up [elliptic integrals of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). The antiderivative cannot be written using elementary functions. Your teacher made a mistake (or is intentionally mean).

Comment: I suspect that there is a $4$ missing, it probably was $\int \sqrt {4 - 4 \sin ^2 x} \Bbb d x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider the ellipse of equation
$$
\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1
$$
and try to compute the length of an arc of it starting from $(\sqrt{3},0)$ counterclockwise, you can use the parametrization
$$
x=\sqrt{3}\cos t,\qquad y=2\sin t
$$
that gives an integral of the form
$$
\int_0^{t_0}\sqrt{3\sin^2t+4\cos^2t}\,dt=
\int_0^{t_0}\sqrt{4-\sin^2t}\,dt
$$
where $t_0$ represents the parameter corresponding to the terminal point of the arc.

Such integrals are not computable in terms of elementary functions and are known as [*elliptic integrals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).